# Eclipse apache sling -- internal error occured while eclipse trying to connect to external sling server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, sling, sling-models

I was trying to setup the Eclipse development environment for Apache Sling    by following the instructions at https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html

I got an error while trying to connect to an external Apache Sling server.

see screen shot below

[image]

I got following the tracing from the Eclipse logs(workspace/.metadata/.log)

```
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Starting Sling Server (external) at localhost".
!STACK 0
java.lang.LinkageError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/AuthScope
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.authenticateHost(HttpMethodDirector.java:273)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.authenticate(HttpMethodDirector.java:234)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.osgi.impl.HttpOsgiClient.getBundleVersion(HttpOsgiClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.osgi.impl.TracingOsgiClient.getBundleVersion(TracingOsgiClient.java:48)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.core.internal.SlingLaunchpadBehaviour.installBundle(SlingLaunchpadBehaviour.java:162)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.core.internal.SlingLaunchpadBehaviour.start(SlingLaunchpadBehaviour.java:111)
    at org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.core.internal.SlingLaunchpadLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(SlingLaunchpadLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl2(Server.java:3541)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl(Server.java:3477)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob.run(Server.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I am working on Eclipse 4.2, Maven 3.0.5, ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Oracle JAVA 8. and the sling I am using  is "org.apache.sling.launchpad-8.jar"

does anyone have any idea?

pleas advise

thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like an OSGi runtime problem with the commons-httpclient bundle. I couple of questions to ask:

- do you use the latest version of the IDE Tooling ( 1.1.0 ) ?
- can you upload the list of bundles from your Eclipse installation?
- can you try a newer version of Eclipse? The latest version is tested and built against Eclipse Luna

Comment: Hello, Robert, to your questions: yes, I am using the latest Sling IDE Tooling (1.1.0); yes, I have uploaded/install the bundles from the eclipse market using the "install new software..." under the "help" in eclipse. yes, I am using the Eclipse luna (4.4.2)

Comment: I notice that there were some extra information for the first time I try to connect with the sling. It says  --- An internal error occurred during: "Starting Sling Server (external) at localhost".
loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/commons/httpclient/auth/AuthScope"

Comment: just an quick update, I have used another PC, install a new eclipse. and it works,  so there must have  be some conflicts with one of the projects or tools that  reside within the same Eclipse work spce...

Comment: glad to hear it works for you. Would still be interested to see the list of bundles in the Eclipse installation that does not work. Can you upload the information from Help → About Eclipse → Installation Details → Configuration somewhere?

Comment: Hello, Robert, I  have sent you an email at your registered email account  with an attachment of the eclipse config of my pc.  hope it helps